# Tutorial ROS enabled model plugin?

Tags: cmake, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'm following the tutorial "Tutorials/1.2/ros enabled model plugin" in order to enable the plugins with ROS, but I have problems when I try to build the code. The CMake throw the following error:

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2

-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2

-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc

-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done

-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++

-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done

-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.26")

-- checking for module 'gazebo'
--   package 'gazebo' not found

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:279 (message):
A required package was not found

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:333 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
CMakeLists.txt:5 (pkg_check_modules)

Cached location of rospack is invalid; searching for rospack...
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

I'm quite new using CMake and the sintax is too complex for me. I don't know why is not finding gazebo package. I'm using ROS Groovy and Ubuntu 12.10.
PD. Sorry I don't know how to give the format to my text.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/602/tutorial-ros-enabled-model-plugin?/) by [raulpl25](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/132/raulpl25/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It looks like you don't have Gazebo installed.  We're only making binary packages for Ubuntu 12.04 at the moment, so you'll need to [build from source](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/Install#Ubuntu_Linux_2).

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0